# How to request a specific IP address from DHCP server?

Tags: networking, dhcp

### How to request a specific IP address from DHCP server?

*This question also touches the topic of DHCP address reservation in a router.*

Background: My home routers DHCP table only allows to create an IP address reservation of an assigned IP. It does not let me edit the table and manually assign the device an arbitrary IP for the next renew.

Answer (score 31):

### using the linux program **dhclient**.

*If you don't have linux installed, you can use a bootable Linux live CD.*

[edit] If you do this trick to create an address reservation for an actual **Windows** machine, first switch the NIC in Windows to a static IP, because after a reboot in DHCP mode Windows may send a DHCP request with its last used IP, which would annihilate your efforts with dhclient below...

The trick is to send a DHCP request with your desired IP address from the same NIC (or better: same MAC address).

Edit the /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf and add the following line (you might have to first copy the file to a writeable location if booting from a CD):

```
send dhcp-requested-address 192.168.1.240;
```

Then stop and start dhclient as user `root`, where your NIC is `eth0` (check by issuing `ip addr show` beforehand)

```
dhclient -r -v
dhclient -4 -d -v -cf /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf eth0
```

If successfull, your DHCP server will fulfill your prepared request. Sometimes you will have to delete the device entry in the DHCP table before issuing `dhclient -4 -d ...`.

Then make that device IP address in the DHCP table of the router a fix address reservation. This will associate the IP to the MAC of the device and return the same IP everytime a DHCP request with that MAC address is encountered in the future.

Comment: The -4 and -cf switches will generally be redundant. The -d switch will make the process stay in the foreground, which is probably undesirable. `dhclient [-v] eth0` for the last step should be enough.