# How to force a Linux DHCP client to get a different IP address

Tags: linux, dhcp

Situation: unconfigured network interface `eth1`.
As root, I give command `dhclient eth1`, and get an IP.
Now I want to change this IP from client side, force DHCP client to get a new address.

Answers of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/42799/how-to-force-linux-to-reacquire-a-new-ip-address-from-the-dhcp-server) only have command to release and re-aquire the lease, but I get the same IP every time, so it does not answer the question.

I am looking for a generic Linux solution, not dependent on this exact environment, but just for reference, this is my current environment:

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04 running as a VirtualBox quest
- DHCP server: VirtualBox host-only network

Also I am aware of following solutions which would work with above: use the VM to set a new MAC address, so it would probably get a new IP too, or simply manually configure another IP for the host-only network. But I am specifically asking how to force a new DHCP IP from client side without rebooting, if such a thing is possible with DHCP at all.

Alternatively, if someone can confirm that DHCP does not support client wanting an IP address change, preferably with a reference, that would be valid answer, too.

Comment: You can't. The server decides what IP address you will get.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, of course, but that does not rule out client being able to reject given IP and request a new one. I mean, this is certainly possible with some trickery (such as by changing MAC address).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DHCP server decides which address it gives to which client. The client can only release and renew it's address, and not ask the DHCP server for a different address.

Most DHCP servers hand out the same ipaddress to a client it has seen before when the ipaddress is not in use at the moment.

It is possible to ask the server for a specific ipaddress, after the current address is released ([How to request a specific IP address from DHCP server?](https://superuser.com/questions/487607/how-to-request-a-specific-ip-address-from-dhcp-server)) although the decision to give you this or a different address remains with the server.