# Requesting a new IP from the DHCP

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp

In Linux, if I want to request a new IP say, for eth0, what commands should I use?

Basically, how do I request a different IP from the DHCP so that it replaces my current one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to request a specific IP address from DHCP server?](http://superuser.com/questions/487607/how-to-request-a-specific-ip-address-from-dhcp-server)

Comment: This does not appear to be a duplicate. The referenced article shows how to make a DHCP reservation. I believe this poster is asking what the Linux equivalent of `ipconfig /release` `ipconfig /renew`

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following -

1. /etc/init.d/dhcp stop  (or equivalent) to stop the current DHCP Client
   listening.
2. Change the MAC address of the device, for example ifconfig eth0 hw ether 01:02:03:04:05:06  - this will make the DHCP server think its a new client, so it should allocate a new MAC address.
3. /etc/init.d/dhcp stop - to restart the DHCP server.